# What's wrong with mysql query

Tags: mysql, select

What's wrong with my MySQL query? Anything that immediately jumps out at you as bad? I'm also not completely aware of what AS does and . between words in the query. Also is UNIX_TIMESTAMP("date") suppose to have "" around date?

```
$query = '
        SELECT 
            object_pk, 
            project_object_fk, 
            tbl_object.name 
        AS 
            name, 
            priority, 
            tbl_category.name 
        AS 
            category_name, 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP("date") 
        AS 
            "date", 
            time, 
            login_pk, 
            concat_ws(" ", title, first_name, middle_name, last_name, suffix) 
        AS 
            person 
        FROM 
            tbl_object, 
            tbl_object_type, 
            tbl_task, 
            tbl_category, 
            tbl_object_category_link, 
            tbl_login, 
            tbl_contact 
        WHERE 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP("date")>1327791600 
        AND 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP("date")<1331420399 
        AND 
            object_type="task" 
        AND 
            tbl_task.object_fk=object_pk 
        AND 
            object_type_pk=object_type_fk 
        AND 
            tbl_object_category_link.object_fk=object_pk 
        AND 
            category_fk=category_pk 
        AND 
            login_owner_fk=login_pk 
        AND 
            contact_pk=contact_fk 
        AND 
            object_status="ACTIVE" 
        ORDER BY 
            time
    ';
```

Comment: Woa, putting the 'AS' keywords that way is sooooo hard to read.

Comment: 'AS' give an alias to the field, so instead of getting "tbl_category.name" key name, you'll have "category_name".

Answer (score 1):

change your quotes for mysql query content.

wether use " for php string quoting , or \' for sql string values inside your php ' quoted string

Answer (score 0):

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP("date") 
AS 
"date",  <-- probably this line
```

Change it to:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP("date") 
AS 
`date`,
```

To be safe.